# JavaScript Html.DropDownList and Model View Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Custom MVC Project. I'm using Jquery but I'm not good at it.I have two dropdownlist created. Apart from other controls, I have a dropdownlist1, anchor link delete and another dropdownlist2 and a textbox.

When I click on the first dropdownlist I'm using a Jquery and fetching the data from controller. The selected value would be displayed in the label and the second dropdownlist would be populated as Viewdata from controller.

All these work I have to do from the javascript/Jquery.

```
function GetRuleCondition() {

     var e = document.getElementById("FilterCondition");         
     if (e.value != "") {
         action = 'RuleCondition/RuleSettings?FilterCondition=' + e.value;
         $.getJSON(action, function (data) {
             if (data != null) {
                 PopulateFilterCondition(data);
             }
             //alert(data);
             // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             //         $("#FilterRule").append(
             //         $('<option />', {
             //         'value': data[i].id,
             //         'name': data[i].name,
             //         'text': data[i].name
             //     })
             // );   
         });
     }
     e.SelectedIndex=0;
 }

 function PopulateFilterCondition(data) {
     addlist();
     var str = data.toString();
     var array = str.split(",");
     var e = document.getElementById("FilterCondition");
     var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
     var numi = document.getElementById('theValue').value;
     if (document.getElementById("LblFilterConditionName" + numi)) {
         var lblname = document.getElementById("LblFilterConditionName" + numi);
         lblname.innerHTML = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     }
 }

 function addlist() {
     var control = document.getElementById("FilterLst0");
     var lst = document.getElementById("FilterLst");
     var i = 1;
     //control = control;
     //if (control.style.visibility == "visible" || control.style.visibility != "") {
         control.style.display ="none";
    // }
     var div = document.getElementById('UnOrderLst');
     var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
     num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value - 1) + 2;
     numi.value = num;
     var divIdName = lst + num;
     var lblFilterid = "LblFilterConditionName" + num;
     //         // var ConditionDrpdwnlst = document.getElementById('FilterRuleCondition'); <%= Html.DropDownList('FilterRuleCondition', (SelectList)ViewData['FilterRuleCondition'])%>
     var content = "<li class='lstclass' id= '" + divIdName + "'><a href='#' onfocus='blur();' class='icon cancel'>Cancel</a><label class='frmLabel' id='" +lblFilterid +"'></label><div class='ddComponent'>Dropdownlist</div><span class='inputBX conTrol'><input type='text' class='inputTXT conTrol'></span></li>";
     //alert(content);
     div.innerHTML += content;
     //var lblname = document.getElementById(lblFilterid); //.value = e.value;
     ////         if (e != null && lblname != null) {
     //lblname.innerHTML = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Please let me know how to accomplish this task as I need it urgently.

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? By the way why are you using `document.getElementById` when you already have jQuery?

Comment: If i understand, you should use [jquery cascade](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-cascade/)